# Remove block from account pages

Tags: php, magento

I have a nav bar being applied to my site with the following code:

```
<!-- catalog.xml -->
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/>
    </reference>
</default>
```

But I do not want it to appear on the account pages. I tried the following, but it doesn't work.

```
<!-- customer.xml -->
<default>
    <reference name="left">
        <action method="unsetChild"><name>catalog.leftnav</name></action>
    </reference>
</default>
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply  `<remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>` in your customer.xml.that will remove the block.

```
<!-- customer.xml -->
<default>
    <reference name="left">
             <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
     </reference>
</default>
```

Edit :-

**Only want to remove it from account pages**
for this you need to remove it from `<customer_account>`

```
 <customer_account translate="label">
         <reference name="left">
                 <remove name="catalog.leftnav"/>
         </reference>
  </customer_account>
```

Comment: But I only want to remove it from account pages, not side wide.

Answer (score 1):

THe cuprit with this sort of thing is usually the order that the updates are being applied.   Your update in the default handle specified in `customer.xml` is probably being applied before the update in the default handle specified in `catalog.xml`.  So `unsetChid` is called first, and THEN the block is added in `catalog.xml`.

Another reason to place all your updates in `local.xml` (update in `local.xml` are always loaded last, which means (within one handle), updates in `local.xml` will run last)

Comment: Ahh, never thought of that. What would be the correct method to add something to local.xml to unset it on all account pages?

Comment: THe code you put in customer.xml should work if you place it in local.xml